# Redirect/rewrite to different internal IIS sites using query string

Tags: redirect, azure, iis, url-rewriting

**EDIT**: Ugh I forgot to put this on Server Fault...

I have an Azure VM that is hosting a web application.

The application will be accessible via the VM's IP address:

```
http://191.238.112.62
```

I want to be able to use query strings to redirect to completely different sites that are **within the local** IIS. For example:

```
http://191.238.112.62/?site=1
```

would redirect to

```
www.site1.com
```

The way I have structured IIS can be seen below:

[image]

Each site has an entry in the systems host file.

```
127.0.0.1 wwww.site1.com
127.0.0.1 wwww.site2.com
127.0.0.1 wwww.site3.com
```

There is likely a better way to achieve what I am going for here so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. Not sure why you want to use query strings for this as IIS is made to do that if you configure it properly.

In your DNS server register all your websites to point to that IP. This is for when you go live. For development the hosts file is a good solution.

When you create the websites add a Host header like below [image: like this]

Now try loading any website by their full name

```
http://www.site1.com
http://www.site2.com
http://www.site3.com
```

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is more info about IIS host headers.

Again, when you go live make sure you have the DNS set up for all the websites to point to the IP address of your server.

Hope this helps.

**Edit based on comment:**

Right, here is how I solved this in the past.
You can do all this with the hosts file but it's less painful if you have a proper DNS server to resolve the names.

The basic idea is to use slightly different URLs for development on the local machine.
All devs would have site1.com point to the IP of the shared server and site1.com.local point to 127.0.0.1. So a hosts file on a developer machine would look something like:

```
191.238.112.62 www.site1.com
127.0.0.1      www.site1.com.local
```

On all development machines you need to make sure you have the .local host header for all sites.

On the shared server you just need to add the right host headers and no hosts file changes. It's actually a bad idea to change the server hosts file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I may not have explained my problem thoroughly enough. Each site won't have its own public domain. There purpose is for individual developers to have there own sandbox and the central entry point for these sandboxes will be the VM's IP address.

Comment: Your edit works great - not sure how I overlooked that, learning curve here for me! Now to go even further with this, would it be possible to setup a public DNS that dev's can use? So this will obviously do what the host file does but would remove the need to manually change and setup individual host files.

Comment: It is possible but you need to buy all the domain names, site1, site2 etc. Once you own the names you can change the DNS entries to point to your IP. another solution is to just buy the top domain site.com and then have subdomains for each of your sites like sub1.site.com, sub2.site.com etc. A nice public DNS solution is dnsimple https://dnsimple.com/r/c5189e2b5db98b?account_id=41178 this is a referral link so if you decide to go with them I'll get some credit :).